# History - LaTeX2e - \newcommand - Why does the mechanism for detecting an optional argument not crank out the case of an implicit [?

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, latex-base, latex-history

*[Please take this question for a moot point/an "academical" issue.]*

The LaTeX-kernel-command `\newcommand` was invented decades before [expl3](https://ctan.org/pkg/expl3), [xparse](https://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) and `\NewDocumentCommand` were available.

`\newcommand` brings along the concept of an optional argument whereby tokens forming an optional argument need to be nested between `[` and `]`.

With macros defined in terms of `\newcommand` that process optional arguments, only the presence of an opening square-bracket `[` is detected as an indicator for the presence of an optional argument. The presence of a matching `]` is not detected.

The LaTeX 2ε-"mechanism" for detecting the presence of the opening `[` of an explicitly provided optional argument is formed by the kernel-macros `\@protected@testopt`, `\@testopt`, `\@x@protect` and `\kernel@ifnextchar`.

`\kernel@ifnextchar` only "looks" at the meaning of the next token.

Therefore the "mechanism" can be fooled by providing an implicit `[` of catcode 12:

E.g., after defining

```latex
\newcommand\mymacro[1][default]{optional argument: (#1)}
```

the following leads to weird error-messages:

```latex
\let\lbracket=[
\mymacro\lbracket something
```

I would expect this to yield the following output:

[image]

, `[` coming from the implicit `\lbracket`.

**My question is:**

**Why does the LaTeX 2ε-kernel-mechanism for detecting the presence of the opening `[` of an explicitly provided optional argument not crank out the case of an implicit `[`?**

This could easily be done by defining `\@testopt` as follows:

```latex
\newcommand\ExplicitImplicitFork[3]{%
  \ForkExplicitImplicit!#3!{#1}![!{#2}!!!!#3%
}%
\@ifdefinable\ForkExplicitImplicit{%
  \long\def\ForkExplicitImplicit#1![!#2#3!!!!{#2}%
}%
\renewcommand\@testopt[2]{%
  \kernel@ifnextchar[{\ExplicitImplicitFork{#1}{#1[{#2}]}}{#1[{#2}]}%
}%
```

(In case of `\kernel@ifnextchar` detecting something whose meaning equals the meaning of `[12` it is obvious that there is something that both differs from `!` and can be processed/examined/"grabbed" as an undelimited argument...)

Try, e.g.,

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ExplicitImplicitFork[3]{%
  \ForkExplicitImplicit!#3!{#1}![!{#2}!!!!#3%
}%
\@ifdefinable\ForkExplicitImplicit{%
  \long\def\ForkExplicitImplicit#1![!#2#3!!!!{#2}%
}%
\renewcommand\@testopt[2]{%
  \kernel@ifnextchar[{\ExplicitImplicitFork{#1}{#1[{#2}]}}{#1[{#2}]}%
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand\mymacro[1][default]{optional argument: (#1)}

\begin{document}

With the modified \verb|\@testopt| this works out instead of leading to inscrutable error-messages:

\let\lbracket=[
\mymacro\lbracket something

\hrulefill

\mymacro something

\hrulefill

\mymacro[optional]something

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: when the original was written it already took a few minutes to load article.sty on some well used machine types and there was no space. What is easy to add now would have required removing something back then, certainly error checking clearly incorrect syntax is something that had ultra low priority

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So historically it's been a matter of saving scarce /limited resources? But who says that using implicit characters as undelimited arguments implies incorrect syntax?

Comment: I doubt it was ever even considered, in 30 years of handling latex bug reports/feature requests I don't think this has ever come up.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This reminds me of how quite a few years ago David Kastrup commented a similar question of mine on usenet: "There are less subtle ways to shoot one's leg." :-)